# Ruby Arrays: Why is the value I print correct, but the value I push incorrect?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm attempting a kata that has had me stumped for over an hour. Essentially, I'm attempting to find the smallest combination of numbers in an array by only moving one element at a time.

The issue i'm having is when I print the array (p arr) I get the result in the terminal I'm expecting. So i presumed I can push that value to arr_collection (which is just a collection of array combinations). When I push the value, and return arr_collection I get a result of duplicate values, not consistent with what I printed on the line before the push.

I hope this makes sense, but the return value of smallest([2,6,1,2,3,5]) should be a 2d array consisting of various array values, including [1,2,6,2,3,5] which is the smallest combination of them all (given the constraint of only moving 1 element at a time).

I'd like to know why all the values returned from this method are duplicated, when instead they should be a mixed combination of numbers.

```
def smallest(arr)
  arr_collection = []
  arr.each_with_index do |num, index|
    unless index == 0
      arr.unshift(num)
      arr.delete_at(index+1)
      #p arr #when I print this, I get the result I want
      arr_collection << arr #when I push this into an array, and return that array below, I just get duplicate values
      arr.insert(index+1, num)
      arr.shift
    end
  end
  return arr_collection #why do I get a return value inconsistent with the values I printed in the each block
end

print smallest([2,6,1,2,3,5]) #[1,2,6,2,3,5]**
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mutating the same array you're adding to the collection after you add it, here:

```
arr_collection << arr
arr.insert(index+1, num) # mutating the same arr that is in the collection
arr.shift
```

And then when you go through another loop iteration, the lines above:

```
arr.unshift(num)
arr.delete_at(index+1)
```

...are mutating that same `arr` again.

You need to add a copy of `arr` to the array so that subsequent mutations won't affect it:

```
def smallest(arr)
  arr_collection = []
  arr.each_with_index do |num, index|
    next if index == 0
    arr.unshift(num)
    arr.delete_at(index+1)
    arr_collection << arr.dup # add copy of arr to the collection
    arr.insert(index+1, num) # no longer mutating the same arr that is in collection
    arr.shift
  end
  arr_collection 
end

smallest [2,6,1,2,3,5]
# => [[6, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 6, 2, 3, 5], [2, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5], [3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 5], [5, 2, 6, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: That's a perfect response, and I've learnt my lesson here. Thanks Diego!

Comment: Consider change `arr_collection + each_with_index` to: `.each_with_object([]).with_index { |(num, arr_collection), index|` which is way more ruby idiomatic.